# How to post and get javascript document into Database

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I've a web page in which i've inserted a ACE- javascript Code Editor. I want to post javascript code into my database and then retrieve. 
for example in case of JSON we use json.stringify and json.parse to post and retrieve data. I'm usieng SAPUI5 backend is in javascript.
 [image: JavaSCript ACE Code Editor]

```
    var conf = model.getProperty("/automation-rule-body");
```

Is there any rule to post javascript code into database ?

Answer (score 0):

If your backend supports REST API use create method of  [`sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#create)

```
var oDataModel = sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, mParameters);
oDataModel.create(sPath, oData, mParameters);
```